# css. Запрет скроллинга страницы без потери управляемости скроллбара

Tags: css

Товарсчи, есть ли возможности в css для того чтобы запретить прокрутку всей страницы, но при этом скроллбар не исчезал, а наоборот продолжал работать, но для другого элемента в документе. Пример можно посмотреть в диалогах в вк, там основной скролл работает, но крутит оно блок диалога а не весь сайт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно что-то типа такого?

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
header{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:green;
}
aside{
  height:calc(100vh - 50px);
  width:100px;
  position:fixed;
  top:50px;
  left:0;
  background-color:blue;
}
main{
  margin:50px 0 0 100px;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(black,black 1px,white 1px,white 10px);
  height:200vh;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<aside></aside>
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Только через css нельзя, можно создать иллюзию как в ВК. Там как раз таки "весь сайт" и прокручивается, а сайдбары, шапка и другие элемент просто зафиксированы через fixed или sticky
Второй вариант, это делать основному контенту oferflow:hidden, а другой элемент растягивать на всю ширину и ему уже делать overflow:scroll или auto, но я так понимаю, это не тот случай.

Comment: а с помощью css + js есть идеи?